# How to stop Buttons from closing a dialog in Cursive?

Tags: rust, cursive

I've creating a complex dialog in Cursive.

```
Dialog::around(
    LinearLayout::vertical()
    .child(DummyView.fixed_height(1))
    ...20 more child Views...
    .child(Button::new("Default", |_| ()))
    .child(Button::new("Wipe", |_| ()))
)
.title("Configuration")
.button("Save", save)
.button("Cancel", | s | s.quit())
.h_align(HAlign::Center)
```

When I click the `Save` or `Cancel` buttons, the appropriate code runs and the program exits.

When I click the `Default` and `Wipe` buttons, the `Dialog` closes leaving me at a screen full of my env_logger messages.  (The program has not exited.)

How can I stop these buttons frmo closing the `Dialog`?

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I wrongly assumed that it was intended behaviour for dialogs to close when any button was pressed.  Writing a Minimal Reproducible Example showed me that I was mistaken.  I found a panic which was hidden by the raw terminal mode, once I piped stderr into a file.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, which is why I asked for MRE. Glad you solved it yourself :)